# Moodle Workspace and User uploads

Tags: moodle

According the [Moodle Workspace docs](https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Upload_users_in_Moodle_Workplace), User uploads can have a column named tenant where uploaded users files can be assigned to a specific Tenant. When I try and upload a csv file I keep getting the following error message: **"tenant" is not a valid field name**. Anyone have similar problems/solutions?

Comment: Moodle Workplace isn't open source. You will need to contact your partner about this.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, it didn't even cross my mind Workspace wasn't open source.